# How to run a spark-shell?

Tags: shell, apache-spark

I have downloaded this: https://github.com/sryza/spark-timeseries, and followed these instructions

```
milenko@milenko-desktop:~/spark-timeseries$ spark --jars /home/milenko/spark-timeseries/target/sparkts-0.4.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

I got this:

```
Invalid command line option:
```

If I try what was suggested in the tutorial:

```
 spark-shell --jars /home/milenko/spark-timeseries/target/sparkts-0.4.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
spark-shell: command not found
```

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the full `SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell` or update your `PATH` environment variable to contain the path to `SPARK_HOME/bin`

Answer (score 0):

bin/spark-shell

this will start Spark session and scala